# How to change the cursor blink color?

Tags: java, swing

I don't know this is possible or not? 
But i want to change the this cursor blink color...which is normally black....
i am making one java-swing based project and in that...one of the requirement is to change the color of the cursor blink....
Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Cursor" is used to refer to the mouse cursor which does not blink.

So, I assume you are talking about the caret which is used in a text component:

```
textField.setCaretColor(...);
```

Edit:

The above suggestion does it for one text field. To change it for all text fields you should be able to use the following at the start of your program:

```
UIManager.put("TextField.caretForeground", new ColorUIResource(...));
```