# How to change the color of | of JTextField

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtextfield

Do you know how to change the color of | which appears and disappears in JTextField? I can't see it because of the dark color of JTextField itself but I don't want to change it, so I want to change the color of |.
P.S. changing color of the foreground doesn't affect this thing. And also how is this thing called ( | ) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The missing piece of information you need is that the cursor thingy in a `JTextField` is called a "caret".

`JTextField` is a subclass of `JTextComponent` which has a [`setCaretColor(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretColor-java.awt.Color-) method you can use.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are asking about the caret color !

This post will help you:

[How to change the cursor blink color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824631/how-to-change-the-cursor-blink-color)